# Set intersection in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, intersection, set-intersection

I want to check if any of a set of given values are contained in a sparse tensor. The sparse tensor is called `labels` and has just one dimension containing a list of ids.

In the end this seems like a simple set intersection problem, so I tried this.

```
sparse_ids = load_ids_as_sparse_tensor()
wanted_ids = tf.constant([34, 56, 12])
intersection = tf.sets.set_intersection(
    wanted_ids,
    tf.cast(sparse_ids.values, tf.int32)
)
contains_any_wanted_ids = tf.not_equal(tf.size(intersection), 0)
```

However, I am getting this error:

`ValueError: Shape must be at least rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'DenseToDenseSetOperation' (op: 'DenseToDenseSetOperation') with input shapes: [3], [?].`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works. However, I am not sure whether the result is what you want.

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([34, 56, 12])
b = tf.constant([56])
intersection = tf.sets.set_intersection(a[None,:],b[None,:])
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(intersection)
```

Output:

> SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[0, 0]], dtype=int64),
>   values=array([56]), dense_shape=array([1, 1], dtype=int64))